# Filtering NSArray from a complex JSON resource using NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying the load the following JSON file...

```
{
    "divisions" : [
        {
            "divName" : "Division Name",
            "divList" : [
                {
                    "itemName" : "First item",
                    "itemVisible" : "1"
                },
                {
                    "itemName" : "Second item",
                    "itemVisible" : "0"
                },
                {
                    "itemName" : "Third item",
                    "itemVisible" : "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

...into a UITableView with sections ("divName" as titleForHeaderInSection, "itemName" in cell.textLabel.text), which is not a problem. The thing I'm having trouble with is filtering data in cells depending on the value of the itemVisible property - "0" for hidden, "1" for showing. My best guess is it should be done using an NSPredicate, for example...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemVisible == %@", @"1"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [randomArrayNameOfItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

...but I have no idea how to actually incorporate this with a fairly complex JSON object.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That mean , if the itemVisible =0 , then U need to skip this item from table right ...?

Comment: why don't use JSon Parser?

Comment: @DharaParekh I'm using NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you decode the json string into object?

```
NSError *e;
NSDictionary object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:op.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

if ( e )
{
    TLog(@"%@ %@",[e localizedDescription],op.responseString);
}

if ( [object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
    NSArray *itemArray = object[@"divisions"][@"divList"]
    //filter here 
}
```

if your case you can simplely set the height of the cell invisible to 0

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //if the cell. itemVisible == 0  , return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Indeed I'm using NSJSONSerialization but in a slightly different way - I'm creating a global NSArray self.contentArray (something like [object objectForKey:@"divisions"]) so that numberOfSectionsInTableView is [self.contentArray count] and numberOfRowsInSections is [[[self.contentArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"divList"] count] - what I need to do, I presume, is to somehow filter elements of that deep array "divList" and I don't know where this should be done.

Comment: i think you don't have to filter the result , you can just set the height of the cell you don't want to 0